# in Silverlight, filling a combobox with data from another source than the dataform?

Tags: silverlight, combobox, dataform

Using Silverlight I have a dataform bound to table A and I need to fill a combobox of this dataform with data from table B. How can I declare this in the XAML code?

Answer (score 1):

If your dataform is inside a UserControl which has a property called "TableBItems" for example, you could write:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem={Binding FieldInTableA,Mode=TwoWay} 
  ItemsSource={Binding TableBItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType='UserControl'}} 
  DisplayMemberPath="FieldInTableBYouWantToShow"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your rreply Boluc.  My dataform is not inside a usercontrol. What I have is the following, could you suggest me a better way?

Comment: Your dataform does not to be directly inside a usercontrol. Are any of its ancestors the UserControl of your XAML? Then that code would work. You just need to make TableBItems a property of the UserControl. You could also use Page instead of UserControl if you are using Navigation Framework

Comment: Boluc, thanks again for your repply.  I would like to know, can I send you by email what I have developed?... Honestly, I will be more than grateful. I am just a beginner in Silverlight and I don't have much experience at this point of time. Thanks in advance